# Why are a lot of users' weekly reputation negative?

Tags: discussion, reputation-leagues

I came across [this page](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/week/stackoverflow/2013-05-19?sort=reputationchange&page=794). Why does every user on this page have a negative weekly change?

Comment: Bounties. You can see their reputation history on their profile.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply! @AndrewBarber

Comment: Also, there can be some *serial upvoting reversed*.

Comment: And on occasion, a user gets deleted and has all up-votes (and all down-votes I expect) reversed.

Comment: @AndrewBarber think it's better to post this as answer, maybe adding some more possible causes for negative reputation change.

Comment: You have an answer here..

http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, in your specific case, the only reputation activity those users had so far this week was setting a 100 point bounty. You probably could also find many with -50 for the week (probably even more than the -100's) Of course, two 50 point bounties would also add up to -100.

There are other reasons users could have negative net changes, and it's possible these could total -100, or any other value. But the -100 is 'special' due to what I noted above.

Other possibilties (which could of course occur in combination)

1. The user was down voted for more points than up voted.
2. Another user who had up voted numerous posts of theirs was deleted, or the votes were invalidated.
3. Posts the user edited for 2 points each were deleted.
4. Posts the user had recently had up voted were deleted.
5. Votes were reversed through the automatic serial vote detection tool.
6. A user that had upvoted their posts was deleted, thus undoing their votes.